# How to shutdown all nodes

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the easiest way to signal all nodes to shutdown?

I created a daemon that runs several launch files in the background, but now that even if I kill the roscore, the other nodes don't end, they just keep running, forcing me to hunt them down and manually kill each process.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242098/how-to-shutdown-all-nodes/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Late answer but worth doing so.
rosnode kill -a will terminate correctly all nodes.

For example before I was terminating all processes by using killall -u user_name, and this managed  the rtabmap node to corrupt the database. With the command I first mentioned, no more corruption happens.

---

Originally posted by [AlexandruIftimie](https://answers.ros.org/users/32443/alexandruiftimie/) with karma: 56 on 2018-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-14**:
`rosnode kill -a` is a nice way to shutdown nodes, as it gives them time to properly close files, stop timers, etc, but do know that it'll only work as long as your `roscore` is running. If that is gone, it won't be able to find the running nodes anymore.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2021-02-01**:
It seems that this doesn't work for respawn nodes, though (unless you have at least one required node).